# Using checkinstall in place of sudo cmake?

Tags: software-installation, compiling, cmake, checkinstall, digikam

I've been trying to compile digikam and as part of that process needed to compile jasper. Jasper developers use `cmake`, I wanted to make a .deb package -- in fact was trying to learn how to make a package to share -- and so tried to do this (which errors as below):

```
sudo checkinstall -D "sudo cmake --build '/home/username/Downloads/jasper/buildlocal' --target install"
```

Checkinstall run with sudo returns a "not found" error (end of 4th line) despite the command being passed to it working successfully:

```
Installing with sudo cmake --build '/home/username/Downloads/jasper/buildlocal' --target install...

========================= Installation results ===========================
/var/tmp/tmp.miGWYgiNzT/installscript.sh: 4: sudo cmake --build '/home/username/Downloads/jasper/buildlocal' --target install: not found

****  Installation failed. Aborting package creation.

Cleaning up...OK

Bye.
```

To repeat, the command

```
sudo cmake --build '/home/username/Downloads/jasper/buildlocal' --target install
```

was successful, but neither `sudo checkinstall`, nor `sudo cmake` with plain checkinstall, nor using sudo for both, worked.

How can I pass the write invocation to checkinstall to make a package here. More details of [all commands run](https://alicious.com/compiling-jasper/) at my blog, but I feel this is enough to answer the question.

Comment: IIRC you're supposed to run checkinstall with the actual install command as argument**s**, not as a single quoted argument. So: `sudo checkinstall -D cmake --build '/home/username/Downloads/jasper/buildlocal' --target install`

Comment: I'll try that, but it may take a couple of weeks before I get chance, thank you.

Comment: @muru that  worked, thanks. If you want to make it an answer I'll endorse it, not sure if it's canonical enough really, perhaps I shoulda rtfm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC you're supposed to run checkinstall with the actual install command as arguments, not as a single quoted argument. So:

```
sudo checkinstall -D cmake --build '/home/username/Downloads/jasper/buildlocal' --target install
```

This is not very clear from the manpage, but [the README](http://checkinstall.izto.org/docs/README) has some examples:

> - Run checkinstall:
>
>   ```
>   checkinstall
>   ```
>
>   NOTE: If you give no arguments to checkinstall it will run a "make
>   install".   If you give arguments, the first non-option argument will
>   be used as the   install command. This is useful when the install
>   command is not "make install"   but something else like "make
>   install_packages" or "setup" or whatever, i.e.
>
>   ```
>   checkinstall make install_packages
>   checkinstall make modules_install
>   checkinstall install.sh
>   checkinstall setup
>   checkinstall rpm -i my-package-1.0.i386-1.rpm
>   ```

Comment: Thanks muru, sometimes it's the easiest things that get you!